# How to select from HIVE tables and separate columns with a delimitator?

Tags: php, hive

Hei,

I have a table 'files' and i am wondering if it is possible to select from this table and separate each column with ';'?

```
$sqlSearchByString = "SELECT fileName as name, description, dimension
                      FROM {$tableName}
                      WHERE fileName LIKE '%{$searchedWord}%'
                      OR description LIKE '%{$searchedWord}%'";

$this->client->execute($sqlSearchByString);
$result = $this->client->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Are you using PDO or what is the documentation for `fetchAll`?

Comment: i am using a library for working with hive: [link] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is horrible or I just don't see where they list the methods, however this should be the right track:

```
foreach($this->client->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $result[] = implode(';', $row);
}
```